# Sphinx issues with specific partial cap words

Tags: sphinx

My sphinx queries seem to behave as expected e.g. if I search for

`CIA`

it will find

`In the CIA`

and not

`is special` or even `is SPECIAL`.

If I search for `LAN` or `VLA` will not find `VLAN` only if I search for `VLAN`

For some reason it breaks with `CTS`. This will find MCTS as will MCT. I can't think of any possible reason this would be happening but it is breaking my searches.

Comment: Also double check the document that contains 'MCTS ', doesnt actully contain CTS somewhere. Maybe in some other field. Its easy to misdiagnose issues like this. also check if enabling partial word matches (eg with min_prefix_len and expand_keywords)

Comment: @barryhunter No CTS in the MCTS matches. Also partial would trip me up if that were the case on VLAN too. Here are my relevant settings: #morphology = stem_en
 index_sp=1
 html_strip = 1
 min_word_len = 1
 min_infix_len = 1
 #index_field_lengths = 1